# How to open MS Edge as minimised with task scheduler?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I created a scheduled task to open MS Edge with task scheduler and wanted to open it minimised.
I tried the arguments: /background , /min but it did not seem to work. Edge still opens maximised. Please guide me to open it minimised.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a `.bat` file containing `start /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"`?

Comment: @harrymc it works dude. But the problem is, I want it to be opened minimised (not in the background exactly). I have Edge pinned in my taskbar. I want it to be opened 'minimised'.

Comment: I didn't get the difference between the two.

Comment: @harrymc the one which you mentioned opens Edge in the background but does not show any active window in the taskbar but does has a background process. I want an active minimised window of MS Edge in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Edge seems to ignore any e.g. `-WindowStyle` passed to it during launch (second instance works, but not the first one).

So instead what you can to is to start the window and then minimize it after its started:

```
start microsoft-edge:
Sleep 1
(Get-Process -Name msedge).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle MINIMIZE $_ }
```

Put the above in a `.ps1` file and run this one from task scheduler.

---

If you don't have the `Set-WindowStyle` function you can paste the one below on top of the script (source taken from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshFunctions/2.2.1.6/Content/Functions%5CSet-WindowStyle.ps1))

```
function Set-WindowStyle {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    To control the behavior of a window
.DESCRIPTION
    To control the behavior of a window
.PARAMETER Style
    Describe parameter -Style.
.PARAMETER MainWindowHandle
    Describe parameter -MainWindowHandle.
.EXAMPLE
    (Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowHandle | foreach { Set-WindowStyle MAXIMIZE $_ }
#>

    [CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact='Low')]
    [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingFunctions','')]
    param(
        [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE',
                    'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED',
                    'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
        [string] $Style = 'SHOW',

        $MainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle
    )

    begin {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Starting [$($MyInvocation.Mycommand)]"

        $WindowStates = @{
            FORCEMINIMIZE   = 11; HIDE            = 0
            MAXIMIZE        = 3;  MINIMIZE        = 6
            RESTORE         = 9;  SHOW            = 5
            SHOWDEFAULT     = 10; SHOWMAXIMIZED   = 3
            SHOWMINIMIZED   = 2;  SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
            SHOWNA          = 8;  SHOWNOACTIVATE  = 4
            SHOWNORMAL      = 1
        }
    }

    process {
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Set Window Style {1} on handle {0}' -f $MainWindowHandle, $($WindowStates[$style]))

        $Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type -memberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@ -name 'Win32ShowWindowAsync' -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

        $Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($MainWindowHandle, $WindowStates[$Style]) | Out-Null
    }

    end {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Ending [$($MyInvocation.Mycommand)]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or it's possible to install the [`PoshFunctions`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshFunctions/) package to use the `Set-WindowStyle` function. To do that 1) Open the Windows PowerShell 2) Run `Install-Module -Name PoshFunctions -AllowClobber` and than possible run your script above.

Comment: Ah nice, I was wondering what the proper way was to get these installed